# Unable to Stream live audio on android 1.5

Tags: android

Hello i m new to android and working on Radio application i gt stuck coz i m unable to stream live audio in android 1.5...

is that possible to stream live audio in android 1.5 SDK..

can any on suggest wht to do???

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem recently.  While this isn't the world's greatest solution, I ran a service that would download the data from the stream and write ## bytes (~15 seconds of audio) to a file, then load it into a MediaPlayer and begin playing it.  The download service is continually downloading the audio and saving it just as the first MediaPlayer is about to finish.  I loaded the 2nd file into a 2nd MediaPlayer object and started it as soon as the first MediaPlayer finished.  It took a lot of tuning to keep this implementation from skipping for a split second each time you switch buffer files, and on the older phones, it still tends to skip a little.